# Refresh (Eclipse-)Project before compileJava in Gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am currently try to build my Eclipse projects using Gradle.
My build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies{ // some libs }
task a{ // do stuff with .classpath file }
compileJava.dependsOn a
```

Because I change some folders in the .classpath it can't find them when the compiler works.

If I try to do:

gradle a

- (and refresh project in eclipse manually after the task is executed)

gradle build [in this case without the compileJava.dependsOn a]

everything work fine.

Is there an option to refresh to project manually in the build script?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing to Eclipse's `.classpath` file from Gradle? That sounds like a bad idea in general...

Comment: There is no other option since I work with some legacy code generator (they produce the classes after the project will be refreshed)